# Porque extender o construtor do Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Estou estudando o Vue.js e me deparei com o método `extend` que na documentação diz fornecer uma subclasse do contrutor base do Vue. Isso eu posso compreender, mas eu não consegui encontrar um exemplo prático do porquê eu faria isso.
Minhas dúvidas são:

- Quais as diferenças entre definir um componente local e utilizar o
  Vue.extend?
- Em qual situação se faria pŕatico o uso de Vue.extend?